# Hyperref PDF sidebar table of content lines numbering?

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, pdf

How can I tell hyperref to generate PDF toc (showed in PDF viewer's sidebar) such that each chapter/section gets its numbering instead of just headings?

Comment: What do you mean by "headings"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load `hyperref` with the `bookmarksnumbered` option.

Comment: you made my day